# Hide element but remains in DOM for internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom, hide

I am trying a list item to be hidden while the following list items will take its place but the hidden list item will be in DOM. 
I'm using jquery hide(). It works well except in Internet explorer. No matter what explorer considers hide() like remove() and removes the element from DOM.

What i need:

1. list item hide while pressing a button
2. list item remains in DOM
3. the following list items takes it's place.

Any help?

Comment: Could you show us your HTML and JS?

Comment: thank you for the response @Ibra. I did it using javascript. Explorer never holds element in DOM using hide() but other browser does. I searched lot, no luck. Somehow it works now using javascript.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue according to your description. If possible, please share your testing code so that it will be easier to help with you. You could refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve